# Is there is repeat Action functionality in Figma?

Tags: figma

Is there is repeat action functionality in Figma?
Like for instance in Adobe Illustrator we can make repeat commands, for reference I am talking about this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hwhWNtuaRYA
Similarly is there is any feature similar to this in Figma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't a way to do this natively in Figma with the standard tools, apart from manually duplicating and typing in the rotation angle each time, or duplicating and holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> as you click and drag the rotation handle to constrain the angle to 45° steps each time.

However, there's a plugin called [Radium](https://www.figma.com/community/plugin/838889318422718953/Radium) which allows you to rotate copies of elements. It's fairly basic, and you might have to group an invisible object with your shape to get the rotation you want, because elements can only be rotated around their centre.

Here's an example in use. The rotated element shown here is a filled rectangle and a second invisible rectangle grouped together.

[image]

Another plugin called [Rotate Copies](https://www.figma.com/community/plugin/841400867216942053/Rotate-Copies) is also a possibility. This one allows you to choose a custom rotation centre

An example

[image]

Another possibility is to use free software such as Inkscape, which has a rotate copies live path effect. This is great because the effect is live and you can click and drag the control points and see what you are getting instantly on-screen.  When finished you can save as a Plain SVG, and import it into Figma as a graphic.

An exmple of Inkscape's Rotate Copies LPE

[image]

Comment: Thank You, this was the functionality I was looking for.